# Use of MediatorLiveData in NetworkBoundResource Class

Tags: java, android, android-mvvm

In Google **NetworkBoundResource** class I am not able to understand the sequence in which **addSource()** and **removeSource()** of **MediatorLiveData** is used.

**For Example--** In this constructor I am not able to understand

**a)** why **result.removeSource(dbSource);** is used just after **result.addSource(dbSource, data);**. I know  **addSource()** is used for **start listning to LiveData**  and **removeSource()** is used for **stop listining to LiveData**. But why we started listening to LiveData if we immediate stop it.

```
 protected NetworkBoundResource() {
        result.setValue(Resource.loading(null));

        // Always load the data from DB intially so that we have
        LiveData<T> dbSource = loadFromDb();

        // Fetch the data from the network and add it to the resource 

            result.addSource(dbSource, data -> {
            result.removeSource(dbSource);

            if (shouldFetch()) {
                fetchFromNetwork(dbSource);
            } else {
                result.addSource(dbSource, newData -> {
                    if(null != newData)
                        result.setValue(Resource.success(newData)) ;
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

**or can't we use the above constructor like this**

```
 protected NetworkBoundResource() {
        result.setValue(Resource.loading(null));

        // Always load the data from DB intially so that we have
        LiveData<T> dbSource = loadFromDb();

        // Fetch the data from network and add it to the resource
        result.addSource(dbSource, data -> {

            if (shouldFetch()) {
                fetchFromNetwork(dbSource);
                result.removeSource(dbSource);
            } else {
                if(null != data)
                    result.setValue(Resource.success(data)) ;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Yes can use this as well.

```
// Fetch the data from network and add it to the resource
        result.addSource(dbSource, data -> {

            if (shouldFetch()) {
                fetchFromNetwork(dbSource);
                result.removeSource(dbSource);
            } else {
                if(null != data)
                    result.setValue(Resource.success(data)) ;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you explain me the first one?